# Backup Cassandra keyspace from development machine and transfer to production machine

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Can someone help me to take backup of the keyspace which I have on my development machine and create a new keyspace on my production machine with and without data.

Answer (score 0):

**Without Data**

On development machine 
export your keyspace into a file.

```
bin>./cqlsh -e 'describe <keyspace>' > keyspce.cql
```

then on production machine 
Open cqlsh and source that file

```
cqlsh> SOURCE 'keyspace.cql'
```

this will created entire keyspace on your production environment.

**With Data**

First create keyspace on production machine see **without data** section

Then take snapshot on development machine.

```
$ nodetool -h <host> -p <port> snapshot <keyspace>
```

And use it on production machine.
Use the **sstableloader tool** to restore snapshot on production machine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am testing on a windows machine. So, can you please give me the steps on windows 10 machine

Comment: I think the steps are the same. Use cmd to run `cqlsh` or `nodetool`.